# Tensorflow build issue with Bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am getting a build error when executing TF.

I have an include file issue. I have installed latest zlib1g-dev, but no luck.

Bazel binaries built from source V0.3.2,
TF command:

`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

ERROR:

```
ERROR: tensorflow/core/BUILD:853:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/core:lib_internal':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc':
~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_madhu/a9aabe45cf3d94341ef4fb777deb58c5/external/zlib_archive/zlib.h'
~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_madhu/a9aabe45cf3d94341ef4fb777deb58c5/external/zlib_archive/zconf.h'."
```

Comment: I know people will advice me to use new Bazel version, but with that version I am getting error as ERROR: /tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:528:19: name 'DATA_CFG' is not defined, hence opted for older version which gave  warning for DATA_CFG and continued.

Comment: Can you double check that bazel 0.4.5 cannot build tensorflow at HEAD? That sounds suspicious. Bazel did rename DATA_CFG to data and HOST_CFG to host, but that was months ago, and all should be fixed now, on both ends.

Comment: I am using modified version of Tensor flow and to my surprise the workspace.bzl does not have any check on the bazel version...                      
under def tf_workspace()

Comment: Is it an option for you to sync your TensorFlow with HEAD and see if it builds?

Comment: This issue is fixed and can be closed, This was resolved by removing all the entries of bazel version using 
rm $HOME/.cache/bazel -fr
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/bazel /etc/bazelrc /usr/local/lib/bazel -fr  ~/.cache/bazel

and updating the PATH to point to the correct gcc version and zlib files.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your `$HOME/.cache/bazel` directory.